# C programming exercise: prime numbers in an array, print using for loop

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, cygwin

I am very new to this community of stackoverflow. At the same time, I am very new to programming (in C), and I am learning it in my university for my Computer Science subject.

I am given [an assignment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTguy.png), where I need to print prime numbers saved in an array. Although I tried to search online for some information, I couldn't find anything useful (and at the same time, I can feel my basics are super bad...).

I need to print the contents in the array, which are filled with the prime numbers; the first 10 prime numbers are supposed to be saved in my array.

However, I am encountering errors, where nothing is printed on my compiler! I am using cygwin on Windows 10.

This is my code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
int primes[10] = {1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23}; // saving the prime numbers! //
int i;
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
        printf("prime %d, ", primes[i]);
}
return 0;
}
```

and [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9YVo.png) is what I got.

I tried other online compilers for C (https://www.jdoodle.com/c-online-compiler, https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler), and I got the desired outcomes. There could be wrong on cygwin compiler (and also this website: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_c_online.php. There is an error about full disk? Not sure what the error is about...).

```
$gcc -o main *.c
main.c:11:1: fatal error: error closing /tmp/cclqdgG9.s: No space left on device
 }
 ^
compilation terminated.
```

What could I have done wrong? Also, what are some suggestions to my code? Is this the best solution?

Edit: I wrote something about not using main function, but I misread my next exercise haha

Comment: Did you read the error message? You have a full disk.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz That is what I got from the online website, not cygwin. Also, what am I supposed to do if I have a full disk?

Comment: The online website has a full disk. You can report it to them or just wait for them to fix it. I'm not sure what we're supposed to make of the picture you linked where you compiler your code several times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is fine except for the fact that you have two variables both called `i`. Get rid of the one you're not using.

You compiled your code twice but never ran it. I'm not sure why you did that or what you wanted to know about that because you didn't ask a specific question.

The online compiler experienced a disk full error. You can notify them about it or wait for them to fix it. Not much you can do about that except perhaps use another online compiler.

Your link to the assignment cannot be the entire assignment unless there's some context. It doesn't, for example, say to write a program or to create a library or anything like that. It lists some requirements, but it's not clear what they're requirements of. So whether you're supposed to create a program or not, there's no way to know.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I completely forgot about running it... I was thinking - compiled, and it's done!! Now where is my output? Haha so sorry for the silly mistake :'')) hope I can work for Ripple one day